# What am I doing wrong with calling the function within another function SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

OK so here is the question I'm supposed to answer:

> 3. Write a script that creates and calls a function named fnItemTotal that calculates the total amount of an item in the OrderItems table (discount price multiplied by quantity). To do that, this function should accept one parameter for the item ID, it should use the DiscountPrice function that you created in exercise 2, and it should return the value of the total for that item.

Here is the script that I wrote in the second exercise with the function that calls it:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION fnDiscountPrice
        (@ItemID int)
    RETURNS money
    BEGIN
        RETURN (SELECT SUM(ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) AS DP_ItemPrice
        FROM OrderItems
        WHERE ItemID = @ItemID);
    END;

    PRINT 'Discounot Price: $' + CONVERT (varchar, dbo.fnDiscountPrice(2));
```

This works fine and gives me the proper discounted item price.

Here is my code for the question that I'm asking:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION fnItemTotal
        (@ItemID int)
    RETURNS money
    BEGIN
        RETURN (SELECT SUM (DP_ItemPrice * Quantity)
        FROM OrderItems JOIN dbo.fnDiscountPrice(@ItemID) AS DisPrice
            ON OrderItems.ItemID = DisPrice.ItemId
        WHERE ItemID = @ItemID)
    END;

    PRINT 'Item Price $' + CONVERT (varchar, dbo.fnItemTotal(5));
```

I'm trying to call the `fnDiscountPrice` function from within the `fnItemPrice` function.

When I run the `PRINT` command that calls the `fnItemTotal` function I get this error in the messages area of SQL Server 2012:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.fnDiscountPrice'.

I have been on this one question now for 2 hours and can not figure out what I'm doing wrong.  My book doesn't have any good references for me to go off of.  Any help would be great.

Comment: You're using a scalar function as though it was a table valued one

Comment: Only table value functions can be used for JOINS. Your function returns a single value and it is a scalar value function. See this link for reference: [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: How would I go about changing it?  Sorry I only ask because this is an online class with very if not no interaction from my teacher.

Comment: Ah ok I see what I have doing wrong  now thank you.

Comment: This is a very relevant article that explains how you can change your scalar value function to table value function and use CROSS APPLY to achieve what you are trying to do. http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3845381

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with calling a function; it's with the `JOIN`.

Look carefully at the join criteria:

```
FROM OrderItems JOIN dbo.fnDiscountPrice(@ItemID) AS DisPrice
        ON OrderItems.ItemID = DisPrice.ItemId
```

`dbo.fnDiscountPrice` takes an item ID and returns a single value of type `money`.  Your join criteria says, "join the result set of this function to OrderItems using the ItemId column in the result set of the function."

The function does not produce a result set, so it certainly does not have an `ItemId` column.

You need to call the function in a scalar context.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnItemTotal(@ItemID int)
        RETURNS money
    BEGIN
        RETURN (
            SELECT SUM (dbo.fnDiscountPrice(ItemId) * Quantity)
            FROM OrderItems
            WHERE ItemID = @ItemID
        )
    END;
```

By the way, I am really confused by the `SUM` call.  I left it there in this example in case you really need it, but I suspect you do not.  If `ItemID` is a unique identifier on the `OrderItems` table, then this is a much simpler approach:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnItemTotal(@ItemID int)
        RETURNS money
    BEGIN
        RETURN (
            SELECT
                dbo.fnDiscountPrice(@ItemId) * (
                    SELECT Quantity
                    FROM OrderItems
                    WHERE ItemID = @ItemID
                )
        )
    END;
```

This version just says "go find the discount price", "go find the quantity", then multiply them and return it.

Comment: Thank you very much Brandon I understand now what I was doing wrong.